# Enqueue and dequeue program runs just cant figure out why outputs dont match

Tags: java, queue, command-line-arguments, deque

**this is the hwk link prompt to help with any questions. read below to see my question. this is just information to understand what my question is**

http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Spring_12/Assignments/prog2.html

Using queues and stacks, in the form of jobs, Im givin a homework assignment that basically takes an input file and writes a command argument to calculate run time. im given an input file seen below:

```
Media Player
100
Angry Birds
140
```

we then type in an argument in jgrasp like "jobs.txt 50 1" which means text file, time slice, and latency. (see link above)
Here is a sample of program execution based on the sample input shown above:

```
C:\classes\cscd300\queues>java QueueSimulation jobs.txt 50 1

Time Slice: 50
Latency: 1

Adding Jobs to Queue
--------------------
Media Player, 100 milliseconds to execute
Angry Birds, 140 milliseconds to execute

Begin Job Processing
--------------------
Executing Media Player, 100 milliseconds remaining
Executing Angry Birds, 140 milliseconds remaining
Executing Media Player, 50 milliseconds remaining
*Media Player finished, total time to execute was 153 milliseconds
Executing Angry Birds, 90 milliseconds remaining
*Angry Birds finished, total time to execute was 244 milliseconds
```

ALL JOBS COMPLETED!

Here is my code: (theres a job class below, a tester, and a linkedqueue class that i use to make my own class with enqueue and dequeue (part of the hwk, i didnt include it because thats a lot of code, just know that enqueue and dequeue are methods) my question is in the tester:

```
    public class Job {
    String jobName;
    int runTime;
    int remainTime;
    int startTime;

//constructures
    public Job() {
    jobName = "";
    runTime = 0;
    remainTime = 0;
    startTime = 0;
    }

    public Job(String _jobName, int _runTime) {
    jobName = _jobName;
    runTime = _runTime;
    remainTime = _runTime;
    startTime = 0;
    }
} 


public class QueueTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        linkedQueue waitQ = new linkedQueue();
        linkedQueue runQ = new linkedQueue();
        String fileName = "no_fileName";
        int slice = 0, timeSW=0;
        if (args.length !=3) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("No command line arguments...\n");
        fileName = args[0];
        slice = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        timeSW = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 
        System.out.println("\nTime Slice: " + slice);
        System.out.println("\nLatency: " +timeSW + "\n");
        Job job = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            System.out.println("adding jobs to queue");
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            boolean first = true;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (job == null)
                    job = new Job("", 0);

                strLine = strLine.trim();
                if (strLine.startsWith("#")) continue;
                if (strLine.length() == 0) continue;

                if (first) {
                    job.jobName = strLine;
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    job.runTime = Integer.parseInt(strLine);
                    job.remainTime = job.runTime;
                    job.startTime = 0;
                    System.out.println(job.jobName + ", " + job.runTime + "milliseconds to excecute.");
                    waitQ.enqueue(job); //enqueue
                    job = null;
                    first = true;
                }

            }
            in.close(); //close the input stream
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Job waitJob;
        System.out.println("\nBegin Job Processing");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        boolean done = false;
        int elapsed = 0;
        while (!done) {
            while(!waitQ.isEmpty()) {
                waitJob = (Job)waitQ.dequeue();//dequeue
                runQ.enqueue(waitJob); //enqueue
            }

            Job runJob;
            while (!runQ.isEmpty()) {
                runJob = (Job)(runQ.dequeue());
                System.out.println("excecuting [" +runJob.jobName + "] " + runJob.remainTime + "milliseconds remaining");
                if (slice < runJob.remainTime) {
                    runJob.remainTime -= slice;
                    if (runQ.isEmpty() && waitQ.isEmpty())
                        elapsed += slice;
                    else
                        elapsed += (slice + timeSW);

                    waitQ.enqueue(runJob);
                }else {
                    int num = runJob.runTime + timeSW + runJob.remainTime;
                    System.out.println("*" + runJob.jobName + ", total time to execute was " +num+ "milliseconds");

                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

*my program works but my output is resulted below. My question is why is it outputting incorrectly? If you can help me make corrections to my tester class to make the outputs match that would be awesome. Just help me find my errors or something I need to add thanks! :) **

```
Begin Job Processing
---------------------
excecuting [Media Player] 100milliseconds remaining
excecuting [Angry Birds] 140milliseconds remaining
excecuting [Media Player] 50milliseconds remaining
*Media Player, total time to execute was 151milliseconds
excecuting [Angry Birds] 90milliseconds remaining
excecuting [Angry Birds] 40milliseconds remaining
*Angry Birds, total time to execute was 181milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code once gain, you'll notice that you are never updating the runtime of the job. After you substract the time slice from the job remaining time, you should also update the time job has executed.

"Angry birds" ran for 50 milliseconds(when 90 milliseconds were remaining) but once you enqueue that job back, you loose that information.

Edit: If you basically want me to give you the answer. Below are the missing bits you need to add.

```
runJob.runtime += slice
```

(You can otherwise choose to renitialize elapsed for each job to 0 and change `runJob.runtime += elapsed, since elapsed already includes the latency) before you enqueue job again.

Comment: hmmm that sort of makes sense...so then what would be the best solution?

Comment: best solution? You are missing something in your code. Simply add  the 50 milliseconds spent on the job in the runtime before adding it back to the queue.

Comment: no your answers right. I havent corrected it yet tho still workin on it.

Comment: im still not able to figure it out how would i do it in code?

Comment: i tried putting that in and now my output is 
*Media Player, total time to execute was 153milliseconds
*Angry Birds, total time to execute was 193milliseconds

so it didnt work

Comment: I think i have given you almost the solution for your homework, if you still can't figure it out, I am sorry I can't help you any further.

Comment: well i tried what you said and i am not getting the answer, so i am sorry i cant reward your answer